# Can I use /testfor on zombies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to use the `/testfor` parameters in a command block to scan for players. But I need to test for zombies. Can you test for things that aren't players? If so then what else can I test for and how do I type it into the block. `/testfor Zombie[~,~,~,r=10]` isn't working. And if not, what would it take to get Mojang to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zombies are entities, and entities can be detected by type. To test for zombies:

```
/testfor @e[type=zombie,x=value_here,y=value_here,z=value_here,r=value_here]
```